# Accessing function parameters in C++ from assembly in IA-32

Tags: c++, function, assembly, x86, 64-bit

I have been learning IA-32 assembly programming. So I would like to write a function in assembly and call it from C++.

The tutorial I am following is actually for x64 assembly. But I am working on IA-32. **In x64, it says function arguments are stored in registers like RCX, RDX, R8, R9 etc.**

But on searching a little bit, I could understand **in IA-32, arguments are stored in stack, not in registers.**

**Below is my C++ code :**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;
extern "C" int PassParam(int a,int b);

int main()
{
    cout << "z is " << PassParam(15,13) << endl;
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Below is assembly code for PassParam() function (it just add two arguments, that's all. It is only for learning purpose) :

**PassParam() in assembly :**

```
.model C,flat
.code
PassParam proc
    mov eax,[ebp-212]
    add eax,[ebp-216]
    ret
PassParam endp
end
```

In my assembly code, you can see I moved first argument from [ebp-212] to eax. That value is obtained as follows :

I wrote PassParam() function in C++ itself and disassembled it. Then checked where ebp is and where is second argument stored (arguments are stored from right to left). I could see there is a difference of 212, so that is how i got that value. Then as usual, first argument is stored 4 bytes later. And it works fine.

**Question :**

**Is this the correct method to access arguments from assembly ? I mean, is it always [ebp-212] where argument stored?**

**If not, can anyone explain the correct method to pass arguments from C++ to assembly ?**

**Note :**

I am working with Visual C++ 2010, on Windows 7 machine.

Comment: I think it is usually something like esp+4 but I am hardly an expert at this, especially not when VC++ is involved.

Comment: Looks like you've copy-pasted assembly. That's not how it works.

Comment: @Tinctorius: Not copy-pasted. It is the final working solution i reached after a lot of googling. But i myself felt it as wrong method (well, ebp-212 didn't make any sense to me).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On 32bit architectures, it depends on the calling convention, Windows for example has both `__fastcall` and `__thiscall` that use register and stack args, and `__cdecl` and `__stdcall` that use stack args but differ in who does the cleanup. MSDN has a nice listing [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/984x0h58.aspx) (or the more [assembly orientated version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff561502.aspx)). Note that FPU/SSE operations also have their [own conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ha59cbfz.aspx).

For ease and simplicity, try use `__stdcall` for everything, this allows you to use stack frames to access args via `MOV r32,[EBP+4+(arg_index * 4)]`, or if you aren't using stack frames, you can use `MOV r32,[ESP+local_stack_offset+(arg_index * 4)]`. The annotated C++ -> x86 Assembly example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff538086.aspx) should be of help.

---

So as a simple example, lets say we have the function `MulAdd` in assembly, with the C++ prototype `int __stdcall MulAdd(int base, int mul, int add)`, it would look something like:

```
MOV EAX,[ESP+4] //get the first arg('base') off the stack
MOV ECX,[ESP+8] //get the second arg('mul') off the stack
IMUL EAX,ECX //base * mul
MOV ECX,[ESP+12] //get arg 3 off the stack
ADD EAX,ECX
RETN 12 //cleanup the 3 args and return
```

Or if you use a stack frame:

```
PUSH EBP
MOV EBP,ESP //save the stack
MOV EAX,[EBP+8] //get the first arg('base') off the stack
MOV ECX,[EBP+12] //get the second arg('mul') off the stack
IMUL EAX,ECX //base * mul
MOV ECX,[EBP+16] //get arg 3 off the stack
ADD EAX,ECX
MOV ESP,EBP //restore the stack
POP EBP
RETN //return to caller
```

Using the stack frame avoids needing to adjust for changes made to the stack by `PUSH`'ing of args, spilling or registers or stack allocations made for local variables. Its downside is that it reduces the number of registers you have to work with.

Comment: +1 - Hi, first method works fine. why [ESP+4] ? why not just [ESP]?

Comment: @AbidRahmanK: because `[ESP]` holds the return address that gets pushed onto the stack by the `CALL` instruction.

Comment: +1 - Oh... I forgot that part. Thank you. Do you have any recommended books or tutorials for a better understanding of this part ?

Comment: @AbidRahmanK: Unfortunately not, as I did most of my learning by fiddling with debuggers and assemblers, aided by the Intel developer manuals.